# How do we allow a user to provide a memory allocator instance to ask memory from?

Tags: c++, c++17, allocator

Let's say I'm writing a library and I want to allow the user to provide their own allocator instance so that they can pack the memory however they would like. What are some ways to achieve this specifically in C++17?

For example, if I use something like new int[5], that wouldn’t be using the users’ custom allocator. What is the equivalent of that statement while allowing a custom allocator?

Comment: Use containers from the standard library.   They are all specified in a way that involves an instance of an allocator type, which the container object uses to allocate and release memory it needs.   There is nothing preventing a user from defining their own allocator types, as long as they comply with requirements that the standard specifies for allocators.

Comment: I think what I'm trying to say is that let's say my library takes in their specified allocator, now how do I make sure that's being used everywhere? Do I have to explicitly type std::vector<int, userAllocator<int>>?

Comment: @rrohak "my library takes in their specified allocator" not sure what this means, your declaration of a vector with custom allocator looks fine though.

Comment: As a cautionary note: The C++ memory management libraries are very efficient and have been optimized over two decades to be good (in the general case). You would be hard pressed to do better. **but** assuming you can show it is worth it then it can be done. But this is non trivial to get correct and should be left as an expert level project.

Answer (score 0):

Any free function that would allocate needs to become a function template.

```
void foo(int arg); // has new int[N] somewhere
```

becomes

```
template <typename Allocator = std::allocator<int>>
void foo(int arg, Allocator alloc = {}); // has alloc.allocate(N) somewhere
```

Any class whose member functions allocate needs to become a class template.

```
class bar {
public:
    bar() = default;
    void baz() // has new double[N] somewhere
};
```

becomes

```
template <typename Allocator = std::allocator<double>>
class bar {
public:
    bar(Allocator alloc = {}) : alloc(alloc) {}
    void baz() // has alloc.allocate(N) somewhere
private:
    Allocator alloc;
};
```

If you need to allocate values of multiple types, decide which is the most natural to require, and use `typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::template rebind_alloc<OtherType>` to get an allocator type for `OtherType`.

Anything that uses any of those functions or classes needs to take an allocator to pass to it.

Quite likely you will use standard library types. You should allow the caller to specify the allocator there, too.

```
namespace rrohak_lib {

    class SomeValue { /*...*/ };

    template <typename Allocator = std::allocator<SomeValue>>
    void frobnicate(std::vector<SomeValue, Allocator> & vec);
}
```